# Is a static variable in java treated as a pointer internally?

Tags: java

I have a question about the key word static. Lets say for instance we have this piece of code.

```
public class Foo
{
private int age;
private static int weight;
.. 
...
}
```

Say in main you create 2 objects. You change the age in one and then you change the weight in the other. Does that mean that the weight also changes in the first object as well? If that is the case then does that mean that weight is a pointer?

I guess my question in a nutshell would be. How does static work internally? Is it essentially of a pointer type?

Comment: Your question is unclear; which "internals" are you talking about? The compiler? The JVM?

Comment: You _can't_ "change the `weight` in [one object]" if `weight` is static.  `weight` is associated with the `Foo` class, not a specific `Foo` object.

Comment: The class `Foo` itself is an object of class `Class`.  In essence (in a very fuzzy sense), a static variable is sort of an instance variable of the `Class` instance representing `Foo`.

Comment: It's important to note that accessing a static member through an instance results in a compiler warning.  That alone should tell you something.

Answer (score 2):

Static variables are shared by all the instances of a class. These are not pointers but all the references(static/instance) will point to same memory block holding the static value. Also important to note that, static variables are associated with class rather than with any object, which means static variables can be initialized and used without even creating an object.

Answer (score 2):

To understand how `static` works, you have to know about two possible kind of members:

- **Class Members**: Shared by every instance of a given class, this kind of members are the ones defined with the `static` keyword. They belong to the class, rather than any particular instance.
- **Instance Members**: Members declared in a class that are not static, belong to the instance. Each one of them will have a particular value defined for it (or none, in the case of a `null` object).

*To answer your particular question*, every instance of a class shares the class members with the others, referencing fixed locations in memory. This sharing implies that changing the value of a class member in a given instance, updates the value for all of them.

Answer (score 2):

Java masks pointers used by the underlying memory management, so you typically don't need to worry about them. But lets straighten out some terminology.

A Java **class** is a blueprint; it defines behaviors (methods) and state (variables). Some parts of an object, specifically those which are *static* are shared by all instances of that class (running in the same execution environment), and indeed do not require the class to be instantiated at all to be accessible.

An **object** is a particular *instance* of a class. All non-static variables and methods are unique to this object and this object alone. When you use *new* you are creating a new object instance of a class.

This becomes obvious when you examine how static methods are executed differently from non-static ones:

```
  MyObject.aStaticMethod();//Note I don't instantiate the class.
  MyObject obj = new MyObject();
  obj.aNonStaticMethod(); //For non-static methods, I MUST have an object instance of the class.
```

Note in the above example the `obj` token is a *reference* (which is subtly different from a pointer) to a particular place in memory. That place in memory is the instance of the `obj`, and happens to include references to code and state variables that are held in another area of memory set aside for the `MyObject` class. In this second area, all the static code and static variables are kept. But usually you don't have to worry about that level of fine detail.